# perl to sum all values in csv file then divide each value by it

Tags: perl, csv, sum, divide

I have csv file, example below

```
     1003036,0.0198942841
     1003075,0.0132738331
     1003144,0.0530953324
     1003149,0.0231666023
     1003199,0.0132738331
     1003208,0.0115833012
```

The first column is an ID and the second is the one I want to do the calculation on. I want to sum up the second column as in this example it would be 0.1342871862 and then divide each of those numbers by it.
For example

0.0198942841/0.1342871862

And then multiple it by 1000000. And this for each.

I have a script below

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open taxa_fh, '<', "$ARGV[0]"
    or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[0]" for input: $!\n};
open match_fh, ">$ARGV[0]_NORM_FILES.csv"
    or die qq{Failed to open for output: $!\n};

my ( $tax_id, $abundance );
my $Total;
my $sum2;

while ( my $line = <taxa_fh> ) {
    chomp($line);
    ( $tax_id, $abundance ) = split( /,/, $line );

    $Total += $abundance;


    foreach (<>) {
        $sum2 = ( ( $abundance / $Total ) * 1000000 );
    }
}
print match_fh "$tax_id,$sum2\n";

close taxa_fh;
close match_fh;
```

The problem is it only outputs one and its always the last value.

Comment: What do you think `foreach ( <> ) ` is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something quite confusing going on here - you read some stuff out of `ARGV` to open your files, but then you also use `foreach ( <> )` which ... opens and reads the files specified in `@ARGV`

This is... almost certainly not doing what you want it to be doing.

I would suggest you probably don't want that `foreach` loop in there at all, because it's effectively *also* going to be opening the same file as specified in `taxa_fh` (And failing to open the file `match_fh` because there isn't a file called that).

So I think you're going off at an odd sort of a tangent.

If I've understood you correctly though, what you're wanting is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $taxa_fh, '<', "$ARGV[0]"
    or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[0]" for input: $!\n};
open my $match_fh, ">$ARGV[0]_NORM_FILES.csv"
    or die qq{Failed to open for output: $!\n};

my @data = map { [split /,/] } <$taxa_fh>;

my $sum = 0;
$sum += $_->[1] for @data;

foreach my $row ( @data ) { 
    $row -> [1] *= 1_000_000 / $sum;
    print {$match_fh} join ( ",", @$row ),"\n";
}
```

Which with your input generates:

```
1003036,148147.300296921
1003075,98846.6098338726
1003144,395386.43933549
1003149,172515.360218338
1003199,98846.6098338726
1003208,86257.6804815052
```

Comment: I was working on a solution before I read yours, and came up with the equivalent but far uglier `perl -F, -lane 'push @lines, [@F]; $sum += $F[1]} END {$,=","; print $_->[0], 1_000_000 * $_->[1]/$sum for @lines' file`